# Opening href anchor tag with window.open() function dilemma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animsition

so basically I would like to create a sort of animation whenever I open new pages. I came across this jquery plugin (animsition.js) which basically take care of all the complicated stuff for me, nice. The problem that I'm having now is that this plugin works as below

```html
<body>
  <div class="animsition">
    <a href="./page1" class="animsition-link">animsition link 1</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can see that animsition works with href links only. This causes a kind of big problem in my code, because in my application I'm not using any links to open new pages I'm using this function below.

```js
window.open("page1.html","_self")
```

So guys I'm seeking for a help to resolve this problem. How can I open this href with window.open ? I meant with all the attributes, classes that this plugin requires? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving proper file location:

**It worked for me!**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Users/Kamala/Desktop/htt.html','_self'); return false" class="animsition-link">animsition link 1</a>
```